# SSL Certificated Validity

Tags: apache, ssl

I'm using an SSL certificate from geotrust. I just ordered and installed it this weekend.
However when I try to access my website using https, firefox (and the other browsers as well) the browser warns that the certificate expired a few days ago.

I guess there could be two reasons:

1. I made a mistake during the installation of the certificate
2. Geotrust did not sign the certificate properly.

First I want to rule out the second reason considering my browser tells me the certificate expired a few days ago. This does not make sense at all.

Is there a way to extract the expiration date from the certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok I got it to work. It turns out I needed to add my IP address to the following line in the ssl.conf: <VirtualHost 11.222.33.43:443>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.... check the certificate in the browser. Click on the not valid warning / broken SSL symbol in the address bar, it should give you an option to view the certificate ;)

Comment: Ok I was able to view the certificate. For one thing the server name in the certificate is wrong. I'm suspecting somehow plesk is overriding my ssl.conf and using another certificate. This dedicated server came plesk pre-installed, even though I never used Plesk directly it I think Plesk is overriding some configurations. In my ssl.conf I've specifically given the address to the correct certificate, but apparently it is not the one delivered to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

TomTom's answer is right on!

Just about any browser will let you see the details of the certificate.  There's always a Valid From field and a Valid To field describing the cert's validity period.

Also - check the subject DN and issuer DN.  The Subject DN describes your server, the Issuer DN describes the signer.  The issuer should be GeoTrust - if the issuer is not GeoTrust, you are not configured correctly, you are likely to be using the cert that came with the web server.

Comment: I think you are right about me using the cert which came with the server. How can I make sure that the server uses the new certificate. I've already modified the ssl.conf.